# Reflecting emotion classification based on the Lövheim cube

Tags: python, classes, python-2.x, bioinformatics

**Background**

I created a simple class to reflect emotion classification based on the Lövheim cube. The code is not scientific at all, and I just did it for fun, but I want all code I write to be as Pythonic and efficient as possible, so I was hoping for some help refactoring it.

**Code Purpose**

Class `Emoter` takes in serotonin, dopamine, and noradrenaline levels and determines the emotion of the emoter via the `set_levels` function. Thresholds for what are considered "high", "low", and "normal" levels of each neurotransmitter change depending on past experience, and values outside of acceptable ranges kill the `Emoter`.

**Review Goals**

I am hoping to make my code as efficient and readable as possible, so any advice is welcomed.

```
class Emoter:
    """
    Create an instance of the class with a name.
    Use set_levels to set neurotransmitter levels for dopamine, serotonin, and noradrenaline.
    Check current emotion with emotion attribute.
    """
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.status = "alive"
        self.thresholds = {}
        self.level = {}
        self.count = {}
        self.thresholds["dopamine"] = [0, 25, 75, 100]
        self.thresholds["noradrenaline"] = [0, 25, 75, 100]
        self.thresholds["serotonin"] = [0, 25, 75, 100]
        self.level["dopamine"] = "normal"
        self.level["noradrenaline"] = "normal"
        self.level["serotonin"] = "normal"
        self.count["dopamine"] = 1
        self.count["noradrenaline"] = 1
        self.count["serotonin"] = 1
        self.emotion = "NEUTRAL"

    def __adjust_thresholds(self, neurotransmitter):
        """
        Adjusts thresholds for neurotransmitter level evaluations.
        A very rudimentary function meant to reflect the effects of LTP and LTD.
        Sort of.
        """
        if self.count[neurotransmitter] > 3:
            if self.level[neurotransmitter] is "low":
                print(self.name + "'s " + neurotransmitter + " levels have " +
                      "been " + self.level[neurotransmitter] + " lately, " +
                      "resulting in decreased sensitivity.")
                self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1] = self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1] + 1
                if self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1] >= self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2] - 1:
                    self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2] = self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2] + 1
            elif self.level[neurotransmitter] is "high":
                print(self.name + "'s " + neurotransmitter + " levels have " +
                      "been " + self.level[neurotransmitter] + " lately, " +
                      "resulting in increased sensitivity.")
                self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2] = self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2] - 1
                if self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2] <= self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1] - 1:
                    self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1] = self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1] - 1
        if self.count[neurotransmitter] > 5:
            if (self.level[neurotransmitter] is "normal" and
                self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2] < self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][3] - 1 and
                self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1] > self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][0] + 1):
                print(self.name + "'s " + neurotransmitter + " levels have " +
                      "been " + self.level[neurotransmitter] + " lately, " +
                      "resulting in increased resilience.")
                self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2] = self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2] + 1
                self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1] = self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1] - 1

    def __add_count(self, neurotransmitter, level):
        """
        Counts the number of times a subject has been recorded at a given
        neurotransmitter level.
        """
        if self.level[neurotransmitter] is level:
            self.count[neurotransmitter] = self.count[neurotransmitter] + 1
        else:
            self.count[neurotransmitter] = 1

    def __adjust_levels(self, neurotransmitter, level):
        """
        Changes neurotransmitter level evaluations based on exact levels.
        Also counts the number of times the subject has recorded being at that
        level and what, if any, changes should be made to their thresholds.
        """
        if self.status is "alive":
            if level in range(self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][0],
                              self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1]):
                self.__add_count(neurotransmitter, "low")
                self.level[neurotransmitter] = "low"
                self.__adjust_thresholds(neurotransmitter)
            elif level in range(self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1],
                                self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2]):
                self.__add_count(neurotransmitter, "normal")
                self.level[neurotransmitter] = "normal"
                self.__adjust_thresholds(neurotransmitter)
            elif level in range(self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2],
                                self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][3]):
                self.__add_count(neurotransmitter, "high")
                self.level[neurotransmitter] = "high"
                self.__adjust_thresholds(neurotransmitter)
            else:
                print("BOOM! " + self.name + " is dead!")
                self.status = "dead"

    def set_levels(self, dopamine, noradrenaline, serotonin):
        """
        Set neurotransmitter levels. Different levels result in different
        emotions. Consistently high or low levels can lead to increased or
        decreased sensitivity to the neurotransmitter. 
        """
        self.__adjust_levels("dopamine", dopamine)
        self.__adjust_levels("noradrenaline", noradrenaline)
        self.__adjust_levels("serotonin", serotonin)
        self.__determine_emotion()

    def __determine_emotion(self):
        """
        This needs emotions for when one or more neurotransmitters are within
        normal ranges.
        """
        if (self.level["dopamine"] is "high" and
            self.level["noradrenaline"] is "high" and
            self.level["serotonin"] is "high"):
            self.emotion = "INTEREST/EXCITEMENT"
        elif (self.level["dopamine"] is "high" and
              self.level["noradrenaline"] is "high" and
              self.level["serotonin"] is "low"):
            self.emotion = "ANGER/RAGE"
        elif (self.level["dopamine"] is "high" and
              self.level["noradrenaline"] is "low" and
              self.level["serotonin"] is "high"):
            self.emotion = "ENJOYMENT/JOY"
        elif (self.level["dopamine"] is "low" and
              self.level["noradrenaline"] is "high" and
              self.level["serotonin"] is "high"):
            self.emotion = "SURPRISE"
        elif (self.level["dopamine"] is "high" and
              self.level["noradrenaline"] is "low" and
              self.level["serotonin"] is "low"):
            self.emotion = "FEAR/TERROR"
        elif (self.level["dopamine"] is "low" and
              self.level["noradrenaline"] is "high" and
              self.level["serotonin"] is "low"):
            self.emotion = "CONTEMPT/DISGUST"
        elif (self.level["dopamine"] is "low" and
              self.level["noradrenaline"] is "low" and
              self.level["serotonin"] is "high"):
            self.emotion = "DISTRESS/ANGUISH"
        elif (self.level["dopamine"] is "low" and
              self.level["noradrenaline"] is "low" and
              self.level["serotonin"] is "low"):
            self.emotion = "SHAME/HUMILIATION"
        else:
            self.emotion = "NEUTRAL"

subject = Emoter("Subject 001")
subject.set_levels(20, 80, 20)
print(subject.emotion)
subject.set_levels(20, 20, 20)
print(subject.emotion)
subject.set_levels(20, 80, 80)
print(subject.emotion)
subject.set_levels(20, 20, 80)
print(subject.emotion)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is` compares instance identity.

`==` compares equality.

Two equivalent strings are not guaranteed to be interned into the same instance.

```
>>> a = 'x'*30
>>> b = 'x'*30
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
>>>
```

Even if there was a guarantee, you should still use the comparison operator that matches the codes actual intent.

---

Operations like the following are hard to read:

```
self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1] = self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1] + 1
if self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1] >= self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2] - 1:
    self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2] = self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2] + 1
```

With the vast majority of the characters on these three lines being the same, it requires the reader to work in order to find the differences. This is bad because the differences are the most important part. The code should make these aspects stand out.

Once you recognize the differences, it still isn't clear what the code is meant to be doing. Extracting all or parts of this code into descriptively named sub-methods would greatly improve the code's readability.

---

```
print(self.name + "'s " + neurotransmitter + " levels have " +
      "been " + self.level[neurotransmitter] + " lately, " +
      "resulting in decreased sensitivity.")
```

Python has a great string format API, and you should use it.

```
print("{}'s {} levels have been {} lately, resulting in decreased sensitivity.".format(self.name, neurotransmitter, self.level[neurotransmitter]))
```

---

[Magic Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants): Get them out of your code. Why is a count of 3 significant? How does it relate to 5? If I need to increase 3, does that mean 5 does too? Do all 3s in the code mean the same thing? Name your constants and give them context.

On top of that, explicitly indexing into a list means that each index has a significant meaning. If `self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][1]` is something different than `self.thresholds[neurotransmitter][2]` they should have names that indicate that. A simple data class or a named tuple would be a better replacement for a list with significant indexing. If I'm interpreting this list incorrectly, it is because the code doesn't make it clear enough what this list is being used for.

---

There are a number of cases where you access `self.level`, `self.thresholds` and `self.count` for a specific neurotransmitter. This makes a case for removing the distinct dictionaries and replace then with a single dictionary that maps a neurotransmitter to a data class containing `level`, `thresholds`, and `counts`.

Answer (score 6):

Various comments in random-ish order.

**Main guard**

It is common to put your code "actually doing something" behind an [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) test.

**Data over code**

Because of many different things, your code contains a small amount of data diluated in a large amount of text. Among the different useful techniques to make things easier to maintain is to extract the data in the relevant data structure.

For instance, you could rewrite `__determine_emotion` with a simple map mapping values to emotion :

```
def __determine_emotion(self):
    """
    This needs emotions for when one or more neurotransmitters are within
    normal ranges.
    """
    emo_dict = {
        ("high", "high", "high"): "INTEREST/EXCITEMENT",
        ("high", "high", "low") : "ANGER/RAGE",
        ("high", "low",  "high"): "ENJOYMENT/JOY",
        ("low",  "high", "high"): "SURPRISE",
        ("low",  "high", "low") : "CONTEMPT/DISGUST",
        ("low",  "low",  "high"): "DISTRESS/ANGUISH",
        ("low",  "low",  "low") : "SHAME/HUMILIATION",
    }
    levels = (self.level["dopamine"], self.level["noradrenaline"], self.level["serotonin"])
    self.emotion = emo_dict.get(levels, "NEUTRAL")
```

I also took this chance to change the order of the emotions to make it clear that what we have is a [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

**Using the right type**

You are using string all over the place, making things quite hard to follow.

- `self.status` should probably be a boolean (with a different name)
- the different levels shoud probably be an enum (or integers 0, 1 and 2 if you don't have `enum` on your version).

**Using `+=`**

In many places, you have `a_variable_with_a_super_long_name = a_variable_with_a_super_long_name + n`. This can be written : `a_variable_with_a_super_long_name += n`.

**Compare values with `==`**

Nothing to add here.

**Define your dictionnaries directly**

In your `__init__` method, you can simply write :

```
    self.thresholds = {
        "dopamine":      [0, 25, 75, 100],
        "noradrenaline": [0, 25, 75, 100],
        "serotonin":     [0, 25, 75, 100],
    }
    self.level = {
        "dopamine":      "normal",
        "noradrenaline": "normal",
        "serotonin":     "normal",
    }
    self.count = {
        "dopamine":      1,
        "noradrenaline": 1,
        "serotonin":     1,
    }
```

**`in range` is not what you need**

Using `x in range(a, b)` is not the right way to check whether `x is bigger (or equal) than a while being smaller than b`. Indeed, this can be simply written `a <= x and x < b` (as in most languages) or `a <= x < b` (quite specific to Python). In you want to understand why `in range` is not the right way to do, try to consider what it actually does behind the scene. If that's not enough, compare `0 in range(1, 100000000)` to `1 <= 0 < 100000000`. (This is true only for Python 2, thanks [veedrac](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40768/veedrac) for pointing this out. Also, here is a [benchmark](http://pastebin.com/xVWVtvvv).)

**Data not in the right order**

Each neurotransmitter is roughtly the same but the information about it is spread in multiple dictionnary. It could be worth accessing the element in the other order (so that for instance, for "dopamine", you get all the information in a same place).

Your code now looks like :

```
class Transmitter:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.thresholds = [0, 25, 75, 100]
        self.level = 1
        self.count = 1

    def __adjust_threshold(self, subj):
        if self.count > 3:
            if self.level is "low":
                print(subj + "'s " + self.name + " levels have been " + self.level + " lately, resulting in decreased sensitivity.")
                self.thresholds[1] += 1
                if self.thresholds[1] + 1 >= self.thresholds[2]:
                    self.thresholds[2] += 1
            elif self.level is "high":
                print(subj + "'s " + self.name + " levels have been " + self.level + " lately, resulting in increased sensitivity.")
                self.thresholds[2] += - 1
                if self.thresholds[2] + 1 <= self.thresholds[1]:
                    self.thresholds[1] += - 1
        if self.count > 5:
            if (self.level is "normal" and
                self.thresholds[2] < self.thresholds[3] - 1 and
                self.thresholds[1] > self.thresholds[0] + 1):
                print(subj + "'s " + self.name + " levels have been " + self.level + " lately, resulting in increased resilience.")
                self.thresholds[2] += 1
                self.thresholds[1] += -1

    def adjust_levels(self, level, subj):
        if self.thresholds[0] <= level < self.thresholds[1]:
            self.__add_count("low")
            self.level = "low"
            self.__adjust_threshold(subj)
        elif self.thresholds[1] <= level < self.thresholds[2]:
            self.__add_count("normal")
            self.level = "normal"
            self.__adjust_threshold(subj)
        elif self.thresholds[2] <= level < self.thresholds[3]:
            self.__add_count("high")
            self.level = "high"
            self.__adjust_threshold(subj)
        else:
            return False
        return True

    def __add_count(self, level):
        """
        Counts the number of times a subject has been recorded at a given
        neurotransmitter level.
        """
        if self.level == level:
            self.count += 1
        else:
            self.count = 1


class Emoter:
    """
    Create an instance of the class with a name.
    Use set_levels to set neurotransmitter levels for dopamine, serotonin, and noradrenaline.
    Check current emotion with emotion attribute.
    """
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.is_alive = True
        self.transmitters = {t: Transmitter(t) for t in ('dopamine', 'noradrenaline', 'serotonin')}
        self.emotion = "NEUTRAL"

    def set_levels(self, values):
        """
        Set neurotransmitter levels. Different levels result in different
        emotions. Consistently high or low levels can lead to increased or
        decreased sensitivity to the neurotransmitter.
        """
        for key, val in values.iteritems():
            if self.is_alive and not self.transmitters[key].adjust_levels(val, self.name):
                print("BOOM! " + self.name + " is dead!")
                self.is_alive = False
                break
        self.__determine_emotion()

    def __determine_emotion(self):
        """
        This needs emotions for when one or more neurotransmitters are within
        normal ranges.
        """
        emo_dict = {
            ("high", "high", "high"): "INTEREST/EXCITEMENT",
            ("high", "high", "low") : "ANGER/RAGE",
            ("high", "low",  "high"): "ENJOYMENT/JOY",
            ("low",  "high", "high"): "SURPRISE",
            ("low",  "high", "low") : "CONTEMPT/DISGUST",
            ("low",  "low",  "high"): "DISTRESS/ANGUISH",
            ("low",  "low",  "low") : "SHAME/HUMILIATION",
        }
        levels = (
                self.transmitters['dopamine'].level,
                self.transmitters['noradrenaline'].level,
                self.transmitters['serotonin'].level)
        self.emotion = emo_dict.get(levels, "NEUTRAL")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    subject = Emoter("Subject 001")
    subject.set_levels({'dopamine': 20, 'noradrenaline': 80, 'serotonin': 20})
    print(subject.emotion)
    subject.set_levels({'dopamine': 20, 'noradrenaline': 20, 'serotonin': 20})
    print(subject.emotion)
    subject.set_levels({'dopamine': 20, 'noradrenaline': 80, 'serotonin': 80})
    print(subject.emotion)
    subject.set_levels({'dopamine': 20, 'noradrenaline': 20, 'serotonin': 80})
    print(subject.emotion)
```

Note how little the `Emoter` knows about the `Transmitters` and how easy it would be to add one. Also, the logic reads much more easily (even though it is still quite convoluted).